# call 2 javascript function in for 1 date label

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using datepicker plugin for my 2 date label and I'm trying to add another function that is date validation.

Here's my code for datepicker plugin

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date From: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date To: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript for date validation

```js
 <script>
 $("#from").change(function(){
    $("#to").attr("min",$(this).val());
});

$("#to").change(function(){
    $("#from").attr("max",$(this).val());
});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the validation on window.load()

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

is the perfect example

Comment: Thanks for the info! :D

Comment: based on your example in datepicker, is it possible that it only shown 1 box or 1 month of calendar only not 3? :)

Comment: Yes, change the numberOfMonths: 3, to whatever you want